# How to distinguish Youtube's iframe from other iframes in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay, coffeescript

I am trying to fix YouTube Video iFrame Overlay and Z-Index Issue, for this i wrote script :
`$('iframe').each ->

        ifr_source = $(this).attr 'src'

        wmode = "wmode=transparent"

        if ifr_source.indexOf('?') != -1

          $(@).attr 'src', ifr_source + '&' + wmode

        else 
          $(@).attr 'src', ifr_source + '?' + wmode`
Its written in coffeescript.
The problem is this, script do fix the overlay issue by adding `wmode="transparent"`parameter in iframe but in my page there are also 10 others iframes i.e iframes of sharing buttons etc. and the wmode parameter also get attached to them.
So I was looking for a way that i will first find the youtube's iframe then add `wmode="transparent"` parameter to it.
Is there any way to do this??
Thanks for your time.
**Edit -**
I have seen that in new HTML5 youtube videos they have added class in iframe here is the sample code:
`<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0"></iframe>`
So now these video can be distinguish easily, but the problem remains same for older youtube videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your $('iframe') selector can be made to be more specific.  I'm not sure what the HTML you're operating on looks like, but for instance, if the iframe you wanted to target was in a DIV with id="watch-player" then you could use:

```
$('#watch-player iframe')
```

and only iframes occurring inside DIVs with id="watch-player" would be returned.

Comment: actually i have same video on different pages with different layout, so i can't do like this. I have already tried it before.

Comment: if there is no way to identify what containers the iframe may appear in, and no way to identify the attributes of the iframe itself -- then there is no way to write a selector for it...